# annoying "Confirm Form Resubmission" message

Tags: theme-development, login

I'm trying to make a customized registration page in front end, but when I try to reload the page in error/success case it display that message in chrome:

> Confirm Form Resubmission

> The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?

my code :

```
the_post();//Iterate the post index in the loop.    
get_header();
$err = '';
$success = '';

global $wpdb, $PasswordHash, $current_user, $user_ID;

if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'register' ) {

    $pwd1 = (trim($_POST['pwd1']));
    $pwd2 = (trim($_POST['pwd2']));
    $first_name = (trim($_POST['first_name']));
    $last_name = (trim($_POST['last_name']));
    $email = (trim($_POST['email']));
    $username = (trim($_POST['username']));

    if( $email == "" || $pwd1 == "" || $pwd2 == "" || $username == "" || $first_name == "" || $last_name == "") {
        $err .= 'Please don\'t leave the required fields.<br/>';
    }
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $err .= 'Invalid email address.<br/>';
    }
    if(email_exists($email) ) {
        $err .= 'Email already exist.<br/>';
    }
    if(username_exists($username) ) {
        $err .= 'username already exist.<br/>';
    }
    if($pwd1 <> $pwd2 ){
        $err .= 'Password do not match.<br/>';
    } else {

        $user_id = wp_insert_user( array ('first_name' => apply_filters('pre_user_first_name', $first_name), 'last_name' => apply_filters('pre_user_last_name', $last_name), 'user_pass' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_pass', $pwd1), 'user_login' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_login', $username), 'user_email' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_email', $email), 'role' => 'subscriber' ) );
        if( is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
            $err = 'Error on user creation.';
        } else {
            do_action('user_register', $user_id);

            $success = 'You\'re successfully register';
        }

    }

}
    ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <form method="post">
        <h3 class="center h1_head">Create Account.</h3>
        <h6 class="center">* Required Fields</h6>
        <!--display error/success message-->
        <div id="message">
        <?php
            if(! empty($err) ) :
                echo '<p class="error">'.$err.'';
            endif;  
            if(! empty($success) ) :
                echo '<p class="error">'.$success.'';               
            endif;
        ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="">
                <input type="text" value="" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="validate"/>
                <label>* First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div >
                <input type="text" value="" name="last_name" id="last_name" class=" validate"/>
                <label>* Last Name</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="" name="email" id="email" class="icon_prefix validate" />
            <label>* Email</label>
        </div>
            <div >
                <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username" validate"/>
                <label  >* Username</label>
            </div>
            <div >
                <input type="text" value="" name="phone" id="phone" validate"/>
                <label >Phone</label>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" value="" name="pwd1" id="pwd1" class="icon_prefix validate" />
            <label>* Password</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" value="" name="pwd2" id="pwd2" validate" />
            <label  >* Password again</label>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="alignleft"><p><?php if($success!= "") { echo $success; } ?> <?php if($err != "") { echo $err; } ?></p></div>
        <button type="submit" name="btnregister" class="button btn right" >Register</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="register" />
    </form>
</div>

<?php get_footer() ?>
```

My question is:

Why this message? How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of general form issue than wordpress specific, but basically you should not submit forms to the page from which they are loaded at. You should have a dedicate URL which handles for submission and then redirects to wherever it is needed (success page on completion, back to the form if failed, etc). You can use the `admin-post.php` end point for that, which operates in a very similar way to the more familiar `admin-ajax.php`.

To use `admin-post.php` you need to specify it as the action url, so your form element will be something like
`<form method ="post" action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php'))?>" >`

might be useful https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/

Comment: sorry ,but it's not working at all